# I cannot set border radius for a div placed inside a td using inline CSS

Tags: php, html, css

I never though this could be an issue at all! I have a `div` element placed inside a `td`, which I want to display as a circle.

Here is the code:

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <td><div style="width: 20px; height: 20px; border-radius: 50%;-moz-border-radius: 50%;-webkit-border-radius: 50%; background: #ffcc00;color: #000;">!</div></td> 
     <td>Something else...</td> 
   <tr>
</table>
```

The above HTML markup is actually being created and returned from a function like this:

```
protected function disclaimer_markup( $link ) {
    $sensitive = $link->is_sensitive;
    $disclaimer = "";

    if( "on" == $sensitive) {
      $disclaimer =  '<table style="margin: 0 25px 10px 25px;border-top: 1px solid #f58353; border-bottom: 1px solid #f58353;font-family: \'Noto\', sans-serif;">';
      $disclaimer .= '<tr>';
      $disclaimer .= '<td style="width: 20px; font-size: 18px;color: #f58353;">';
      $disclaimer .= '<div style="width: 20px; height: 20px;-moz-border-radius: 10px;-webkit-border-radius: 10px;border-radius: 10px;background: #f58353; color: #ffffff; text-align: center;font-weight: bold;border-collapse: separate;">!</div>';
      $disclaimer .= '</td>';
      $disclaimer .= '<td style="font-size: 12px; width: color: #f58353;font-style: italic;"><span style="color: #f58353;">This article has been shared with employees only. Some information in this article may not be appropriate to share with customers or external audiences</span></td>';
      $disclaimer .= '</tr>';
      $disclaimer .= '</table>';
    }

    return $disclaimer;
  }
```

The border radius does not work at all. I checked both Chrome and Firefox.

The most surprising thing is when I checked page source, the entire `border-radius` properties are simply ignored and not rendered at all!

The rendered output looks like this:

```
<div style="width: 20px; height: 20px; background: #ffcc00;color: #000;">!</div>
```

What's went wrong? Please suggest.

Comment: that html is working (radius works) for me on Chrome

Comment: its some dependent file/code which is creating issue! plz find it.

Comment: Here is a fiddle with the output from your PHP: https://jsfiddle.net/keu5yaaL/ and it works in all browsers. So fire up your inspect tools and look for which styles override the inline ones.